# JavaFX: Navigating through a Canvas within a ScrollPane of equal dimensions

Tags: user-interface, canvas, javafx, scrollpane

I created a 10 000 x 10 000 pixel canvas, placed it inside a scroll pane with dimensions 300 x 300. This was implemented fine. The whole grid was drawn and I could scroll through it.

I'm tasked to instead create the same functionality, except with a 300 x 300 canvas instead. As speed is important in this program, I'm told this would work much faster.

My problem is that when I do this, I lose access to the scroll bars on the bottom and right of the scroll pane. How do I regain access to those scroll bars, to physically scroll?

The canvas is updating at 60 steps per second. What's being drawn is a square grid from the information in a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Since the the viewport handling will be done by the drawing logic, it's rather easy to create a "ScrollPane" yourself using a `GridPane`:

```
public static ScrollBar createScrollBar(Orientation orientation, double fullSize, double canvasSize) {
    ScrollBar sb = new ScrollBar();
    sb.setOrientation(orientation);
    sb.setMax(fullSize - canvasSize);
    sb.setVisibleAmount(canvasSize);
    return sb;
}
```

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

ScrollBar vScroll = createScrollBar(Orientation.VERTICAL, 10000, 300);

ScrollBar hScroll = createScrollBar(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 10000, 300);

GridPane scrollPane = new GridPane();
scrollPane.addColumn(0, canvas, hScroll);
scrollPane.add(vScroll, 1, 0);
```